# Cloudflare CNAME flattening and Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare CNAME flattening to and Cloudflare Page Rules to speed up my site that is also behind an Nginx proxy server.  I am coming across an infinite redirect loop and trying to debug.

I am trying to accomplish the following (and wanting to rely on Cloudflare's speed for as much as possible)

1. Default to SSL (currently have always use https Cloudflare page rule)
2. Forward root domain.com to www.domain.com
3. Enabled full SSL because I have 443 set up on Nginx
4. My root record is set up as an alias for my www.domain.com record

I've enabled the Cloudflare button for the root and www a records, but I keep getting an infinite redirect loop.  When i disable the button for the www record, everything works.  However, I do not get any of the cloudflare caching benefits.

My nginx config is below:

```
enter code here

server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name *.domain.com;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen      [::]:443 ssl spdy;
  listen      443 ssl spdy;
  server_name *.domain.com;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;
  ssl_certificate     /tls/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /tls/server.key;

  keepalive_timeout   70;
  add_header          Alternate-Protocol  443:npn-spdy/2;
  location    / {

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types    text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level  6;

    proxy_pass  http://app;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }

}

upstream app {
  server 172.17.0.11:5000;
}
```

How should I go about doing what I want to efficiently (fast)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure your SSL mode is set to Full or Full (Strict), if it's set to Flexible you will likely receive an infinite redirect loop.

If in doubt, see this article about what [CloudFlare SSL options do](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-What-do-the-SSL-options-mean-).

[image: CloudFlare SSL Options]